# Probability: Union and Conditional Union

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have $P(A\cup C|B)$

Does it equal to $P(A|B)+P(C|B)-P(A\cap C |B)$

If A,C are mutually exclusive, is it same as $P(A|B)+P (C|B)$?

Comment: What you understand under $P((A|B)\cup (C|B))$?

Comment: I dont know, looks like A given B union C given B?

Comment: What does $(A|B)\cup(C|B)$ mean?  $A|B$ is not a set.

Comment: Edited, does it make sense this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes."  We have
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(A\cup C|B)&=\frac{\Pr((A\cup C)\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}\\
&=\frac{\Pr((A\cap B)\cup (C\cap B))}{\Pr(B)}\\
&=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(C\cap B)-\Pr(A\cap C\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}\\
&=\Pr(A|B)+\Pr(C|B)-\Pr(A\cap C|B)
\end{align}$$

Now if $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive, or mutually exclusive given $B$, this reduces to $\Pr(A|B)+\Pr(C|B)$.

Answer (score -1):

Application $A \to {\rm Pr}(A|B)$ is a probability, so the answer is yes.

In France, we note ${\rm Pr}_B(A)$. Both notations have pros and cons...